# UTF-8 characters in header in HTTPURLConnection Java

Tags: java, encoding, httpurlconnection

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("something", "***UTF-8 characters here***");
```

In the server side (nodejs), something == ?????. How can we send those characters in header in UTF-8?

Comment: what do you want people to look into ?

Comment: Are you sure it’s not NodeJS that somehow botches decoding those characters? Have you tried looking at what is really going over the wire, e.g. with wireshark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP header values can be US-ASCII characters only.

You can URL-encode characters outside this range, thereby only sending allowed characters.